# Does $IJ=IK\implies J=K$ always hold for integral domain and finitely generated nonzero ideal $I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

Let $R$ be a commutative integral domain, $I,J,K$ three ideals of $R$ with $I\neq (0)$ being finitely generated. Then does $IJ=IK$ imply $J=K$?

With Nakayama lemma, I can prove it if one of $J$ and $K$ equals to $R$. And I also know it holds when $R$ is a Prüfer domain or $I$ is singly generated.

Comment: Maybe I did not fully understand your statement but $IJ=IK$ always (for any $J$ and $K$) holds whenever $I=\{0\}$ ?

Comment: @ClémentGuérin  Ah, I missed this case, now it has been fixed. Thank...

Comment: The example posted in the accepted answer is well known. Much more interesting is to find such an example in $K[X,Y]$ which is integrally closed but not Prufer (or in any other integrally closed domain which isn't Prufer). Unfortunately I don't have one.

Comment: I forgot to mention the following result: an integral domain $R$ is Prufer iff $R$ is integrally closed and satisfies the cancellation property. (This shows why it's more interesting to impose $R$ integrally closed when look for an example as you wanted.)

Comment: @user26857 Thank you very much, honestly I think what's in your comment is more interesting than what I posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think taking $R:=F[X,Y]$, $I:=(X,Y)$, $J:=(X^2,Y^2)$ and $K:=(X^2,XY,Y^2)$ might be a more interesting counterexample, as user26857 noted in the comment.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't always hold. For example, Let $R:=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$, take $I:=(2,1+\sqrt{-3})$, $J:=(2)$ and $K:=(1+\sqrt{-3})$, then $IJ=IK$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/44769/121097

Comment: @user26857 That's exactly what I want, thank you very much!