# mulitiplication of module and ideal

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Is this right?

Let  $M$ finitely generated a $A$ module and $a$,$b$ ideals of $A$ s.t $a$,$b$ contain $ann(M)$.

$aM=bM$ imply $a=b$.

I got partial result when a=A by Nakayama lemma but i can neither prove or disprove the original statement.

Comment: This is not true. $a$ and $b$ could be distinct ideals contained within the annihilator of $M$.

Comment: But what about when a and b contain  annihilator?
and I modified the question.

Comment: @atssit _Do not_ add hypotheses after part of your question gets answered. In this case, your addition did not change the situation and the solution given is still a counterexample. But in general you should not move the goalposts on existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer an answer for the first one because sometimes examples can be tough to find.

> Is this right? (Let $M$ a $A$ module and $a$,$b$ ideals of $A$ s.t $a$,$b$ contain $ann(M)$. $aM=bM$ imply $a=b$.)

It isn't right.

Let $R$ be any primitive ring that isn't simple, like the endomorphism ring of an infinite dimensional vector space, and let $M$ be a faithful simple module for that ring. Then $IM=M$ for every nonzero ideal $I$ of $R$, and all $I$'s contain the annihilator of $M$ (which is zero) and there are many such $I$'s.

> If it's wrong, when [does] this hold.

Gonna pass on that. You owe us efforts of your own along these lines.

> Let  $M$ finitely generated a $A$ module and $a$,$b$ ideals of $A$ s.t $a$,$b$ contain $ann(M)$. $aM=bM$ imply $a=b$.

Still wrong after your revision. The example I gave is finitely generated (it is cyclic.)

Comment: Thanks for your exmaple but i can't come up with any idea. Could you give me any advice. And I modified the question.

Comment: This solution still gives a counterexample for the modified question. Don't move the goalposts by editing. If you want to ask a fundamentally different question ask in another post.

Comment: I apologize for editing the question.
If M is finitely generated and M=IM, then there exsits s in I s.t 1+s is in ann(M).
So when I contain ann(M), then 1 is in I, that is I=A.
Your answer seems to contradict this.

Comment: @atssit I don't believe that formulation of Nakayama's lemma holds for rings that aren't commutative.  Have you secretly been assuming commutativity this whole time?

Comment: I'm ashamed that I was unaware that the examples you gave are noncommutative!
I  also implicitly assumed commutativity this whole time.

Comment: I find counter example in a related question.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310230/does-ij-ik-implies-j-k-always-hold-for-integral-domain-and-finitely-generated?rq=1